# Trouble redirecting urls in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to set up an Nginx redirect where `domain.com/story/urlname` would redirect to `domain.com/clientstories/urlname`. Essentially need to redirect from one sub-path to another. I tried the following but that kept redirecting me to `domain.com/clientstories(.*` What am I missing here?

```
location /story/(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/clientstories$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location` block is missing the regular expression operator and an anchor for the beginning of the URI. The `return` statement is missing the separator after `clientstories` because it is not part of the capture.

Example using a regular expression `location`:

```
location ^/story(/.*)$ {
    return 301 /clientstories$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Example using a prefix `location`:

```
location /story/ {
    rewrite ^/story(/.*)$ /clientstories$1 permanent;
}
```

Regular expression locations are evaluated sequentially, and take precedence over prefix locations, so presence of other locations in your configuration may be significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.